# pandas redefine isnull to ignore 'NA'

Tags: python, pandas

As part of a data profiling exercise, I'm reading excel sheets into pandas dataframes.

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx').parse(0)
nullcounts = df.isnull().sum().to_frame('null_records')
```

Produces a nice frame with the null count for every series in my dataframe. But if the string 'NA' appears in a row of data, I don't want the `isnull` operation to return `True`.

Is there a simple way to do this without hard coding a rule for a specific column/dataframe?

Edit: It appears that the NAs in my source data are being ignored when being read into pandas, since when I load the data and compare visually I see `NaN` where in excel there was `NA`.

Comment: the string 'NA' will not return `True` for null testing, how to do you know this is happening, can you post some raw data and code that reproduces this

Comment: good point, question edited above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) is possible define which values are converted to `NaN` with parameter `keep_default_na` and `na_values`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
print (df)
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1  3.0  6.0

nullcounts = df.isnull().sum().to_frame('null_records')
print (nullcounts)
   null_records
a             1
b             1

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',keep_default_na=False,na_values=['NaN'])
print (df)
    a    b
0  NA  NaN
1   3  6.0

nullcounts = df.isnull().sum().to_frame('null_records')
print (nullcounts)
   null_records
a             0
b             1
```

Comment: the string 'NA' should not return `True` for `isnull`, null-ness only applies to numeric types, try it with the string 'NA'

Comment: sure, so I use replace.

Comment: But isn't the OP stating that they think that 'NA' is returning True though for `isnull`? This is why I asked for a reproducible example

Comment: @EdChum - yes, it is a bit unclear - I understand it in df are `NA` and `NaN` values.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - have rephrased my question a bit. looks like the solution is in changing the `pd.ExcelFile` parameters